# From Google Maps CID to Place ID

Tags: google-places-api

I have a bunch of links to google maps in the form of `https://maps.google.com/?cid=<identifier>`.

How can you go from that CID to a Place ID that can be used with the Google Places API? Is there any API endpoint that you can use to convert these URLs into the new places?

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a better way? This is killing me, I need the exact same thing.

Comment: @j_walker_dev No :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got lucky and found an undocumented api. If you have the CID, you can call the api like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?cid=${CID}&key=YOUR_API_KEY`.

I just changed `place_id=${the_end_val_i_needed}` to `cid=${CID}` and in the json response is the `place_id`.

Comment: Are there any costs for this api call?

Comment: This API is now documented at: [https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) There are costs involved. Currently $17/1000 requests, note that you do get free credit.

Comment: This is great and still works! Luckily, I only need it to run once because it doesn't seem reliable for production if it's undocumented. I don't see any reference to a CID parameter in the current docs as mentioned by @KriiV.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this API hidden parameter to get Place ID.  Usage: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?cid=YOUR_CID&key=YOUR_KEY

It returns a result contains formatted address, place_id, name of the address and GPS coordinater.

Please see my blog to see more detail: https://leonbbs.blogspot.com/2018/03/google-map-cid-to-placeid-or-get.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19026331)

Comment: I have already included essential parts in the answer. Please don't delete again.

Comment: Any time you have to visit an external site to get the details it's a link-only answer.

Comment: The second sentence is a direct answer.

Answer (score 5):

The only way that I am aware of is scraping the regular html response. This can change of course at any time at Googles discretion and I would be interested in a better solution as well.

**As of now** e.g. the source of `http://maps.google.com/?cid=15792901685599310349` has a json response embedded. It starts with `cacheResponse([[[` and ends with `]);`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir=ltr>
  <head>
    <script nonce="W6BFnVsL4HLAdFCwYXZY">
      mapslite = {
        START_PERF: (window.performance && window.performance.now) ?
                        window.performance.now() : +(new Date())
      };
      mapslite.getBasePageResponse = function(cacheResponse) {
        delete mapslite.getBasePageResponse;
        cacheResponse([[[2556.225486744883,-122.3492774,47.6205063], ... removed ... ]);
      };
      executeOgJs = function() {
```

Within this json array element 8 contains a sub array. Element 27 is the `place_id`.

In case of the Space Needle with CID `15792901685599310349` the place id is `ChIJ-bfVTh8VkFQRDZLQnmioK9s`.

Only Google knows why they don't provide a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Request to the provided link, parse the HTML page of the response body, and extract the metadata containing the place's name which can be used to find the place by the Place API.

For example, we have a link:

```
maps.google.com/?cid=13226830714359798441
```

then the request page contains metainfo:

```
<meta content="Big Ben · London SW1A 0AA, United Kingdom"
      itemprop="name">

<meta content="Big Ben · London SW1A 0AA, United Kingdom" 
      property="og:title">

<meta content="Big Ben · London SW1A 0AA, United Kingdom"
      property="og:site_name">
```

Gist of the sender and metadata extractor:
https://gist.github.com/asilichenko/b0000eb1562c9e4e75b0d43d799260bc